# c# panel image only updates half the time

Tags: c#, winforms

For my programming class we are required to make a memory match game.  When the player clicks on a panel an image is displayed. The player clicks on two panels, if the images match they are removed, if they are different they are turned face down.

The problem I am having with this is that only the image from the first panel gets displayed, even though I am using the same line of code to display the images from both panels, and use Thread.Sleep to pause the program after the second tile has been picked.  I don't understand why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

```
    private void tile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tileName = (sender as Panel).Name;
        tileNum = Convert.ToInt16(tileName.Substring(5)) - 1;
        //figure out if tile is locked
        if (panelArray[tileNum].isLocked == false)
        {                 
            pickNum++;
            //although the following line of code is used to display the picture that is stored in the tile array
            //what is happening is that it will only display the picture of the first tile that has been picked.  
            //when a second tile is picked my program seems to ignore this line completely, any ideas?
             panelArray[tileNum].thisPanel.BackgroundImage = tiles[tileNum].tileImage;

            if (pickNum == 1)
            {                    
                pick1 = tileNum;                    
                panelArray[tileNum].isLocked = true;    
            }

            else
            {                    
                pick2 = tileNum;                  
                UpdateGameState();                   
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGameState()
    {       
        Thread.Sleep(1500); 

        if (tiles[pick1].tag == tiles[pick2].tag)//compares tags to see if they match.
        {
            RemoveTiles();
        }
        else
        {
            ResetTiles();
        }

        pickNum = 0;
        guess += 1;
        guessDisplay.Text = Convert.ToString(guess);

        if (correct == 8)
        {
            CalculateScore();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `Refresh()` or `Invalidate()` after picking second panel? Form might not have time to refresh itself if you call `Sleep()` immediately...

Comment: *Never* use Thread.Sleep() if your program needs to do work.  Like painting the second image.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: Problem solved. Using Refresh() after updating the background image seems to have solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(sender as Panel).BackgroundImage = tiles[tileNum].tileImage;
```

you have to be sure that your tile_Click method is associated to both panel...